# Couchbase lite android unexpected behavior

Tags: android, database, couchbase-lite, nosql

1. Creating a document and within a nested document with some properties and values

> document : {
>         "key" : "value",
>         "key2" : "value2",
>         "nested_object" : [{
>            ... nested object properties
>         }]
>       }

2. Defined a view and query to get all documents from database of this document type (adjacent to https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html and https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html)
3. First query -> I get the document with nested document (expected)
4. I change criteria for query, get no results (expected)
5. I change criteria same as in step 3, query returns document **WITHOUT** the nested object (unexpected)

Question: Is this expected? How can the same query return first with, then without the nested object?

Here a gist :

https://gist.github.com/ramden/4e268d31239c4578f6f9a01dfa5bd930

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  Can you post your view and query code?

Comment: I added a gist at the bottom of the question

Comment: A document is just JSON, and it's always returned as a whole including all nested objects. If you're missing a nested object, it is probably a side effect of the way you're mapping JSON to Java objects (which is something I'm not familiar with, so I can't help you there.)

Comment: Response added to the gist.